# How to properly code up a function call logging decorator?

Tags: python

Consider the example:

debug.py:

```
import logging

class log_funcname:

    def __init__(self, the_logger):
        self.the_logger = the_logger

    def __call__(self, fn):
        def simply_call(*args, **kwargs):
            self.the_logger.critical(fn.func_name)
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return simply_call

logger = logging.getLogger()

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(lineno)s")
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(ch)

@log_funcname(logger)
def hello():
  pass

hello()
```

output:

```
$ python debug.py
10
```

I meant to create a function that calls the logger, passing it the line number and file name from where the execution really happened. If I wanted the example app to ouput 25 instead of 10, what should I change then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093075/how-can-i-log-current-line-and-stack-info-with-python but there is a solution there using ``inspect.currentframe()`` :D

Comment: I know line numbers are somewhat central to your question, but by adding line numbers like that you make so much harder for others to test out your code.

Comment: See also [How to use inspect to get the caller's info from callee in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3711184/222914)

Comment: right, use the module `inspect` you will find everything there

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: why would it make it harder?

Comment: @d33tah: Now it's just a simple copy and paste. Not everyone is a wiz with editors to remove the leading line numbers, etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I understood you're talking about code numbers in the code, not debug messages.