# How to log nested function names while logging

Tags: python, logging

I am logging the function name in my application logs using `%(funcName)`, but this only captures the function name which executes the code.

let's say that func_C is called form func_B and func_B is being called from func_A, then i would also like this information in log. How can i fetch this info in my log message?

Comment: This may help you:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I log current line, and stack info with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093075/how-can-i-log-current-line-and-stack-info-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `stack_info` keyword argument:

```
import logging
    
def C():
    logging.debug('C called', stack_info=True)
    
def B():
    C()
    
def A():
    B()
    
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
A()
```

results in

```
DEBUG:root:C called
Stack (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Python310/nested.py", line 13, in <module>
    A()
  File "/home/runner/Python310/nested.py", line 10, in A
    B()
  File "/home/runner/Python310/nested.py", line 7, in B
    C()
  File "/home/runner/Python310/nested.py", line 4, in C
    logging.debug('C called', stack_info=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is pass the outer function's name to the inner function with an argument and then you can log that in the inner function from the passed variable. So func name A gets passed to func B, then func name A and func name B get passed to func C where you log all three.